# how to get profile value from a jar in spring maven without spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven

in a traditional spring project(non spring boot) with maven, I have `projectA` and `projectB`, they are packaged as `war`. There is another `common` which packaged as `jar`. Both `projectA` and `projectB` depends on `common`.

I want to define profile in `common` and use the profile values in `projectA` and `projectB`, how can I do that?

the pom file of `common` looks like as follows:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <env>prod</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <env>test</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <finalName>common</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

there are three profile files under `common`: `application-dev.properties`, `application-test.properties` and `application-prod.properties`, then how can I use the key-value of `common` properties file base on profile in `projectA` and `projectB`?

Comment: I don't understand mixing maven profiles with spring profiles; what does one have to do with the other?  Maven uses inheritance, so if your project extended common (e.g., had the parent of common), it would have access to the profiles defined in common.